# How to create a polygon with coordinates you read from a file with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display an image of the District of Columbia and I have 240 coordinates to create a polygon with tKinter. The coordinates are separated by a space and I want to 'split' them and append them to x and y. The program I have so far attached below is not running anything and just says "operation complete". The expected outcome is a display of DC in a window that is 640x480.

```
from Tkinter import Tk,Canvas
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg="white")
f = open("lab312.txt")
points = []
for n in range (1, 240):
   z = f.readline()
   coords= z.split(" ")
   x=float(coords[0])
   y=float(coords[1])
   points.append((12820*x+300,324*y+2198))
root.mainloop()
```

The results I received was a window that wasn't 480x640 and it had nothing on it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Specifically, provide an input example and a trace of your result (i.e. `print(points)`) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: For starters, you don't add anything to the Canvas, you don't layout the Canvas, and your coordinates are wildly off the screen. Fix those and if you still need help provide a [mcve].

Comment: Even after your edit, I don't see you writing to the canvas. Perhaps a call to `canvas.create_polygon()` might move you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example that uses a list of strings as the input 'file'.  Your main issue will be translating from the coordinates used in your data file to canvas plot coordinates with x and y in their respective ranges, with y increasing down.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=640, height=480, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
f = [
'50 50',
'100 10',
'200 200',
'100 300',
'75 200',
]
points = []
for line in f:
    x, y = map(int, line.split())
    points.extend((x, y))
canvas.create_polygon(*points, fill='red')
root.update()
```

Comment: I am having trouble with converting  the string into a float to match my data values. Also, how do I change or append the coordinates I read to scale it to fit in the window?

Comment: First read http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-window-coords.html and notice that life is simpler without scrolling.  You question is how to convert world coordinates (your file input) to canvas/window coordinates, which are usually called viewport coordinates in computer graphics literature.  The exact answer depends on the coordinate limits in the two systems.  https://www.cs.mtsu.edu/~jhankins/files/4250/notes/WinToView/WinToViewMap.html gives the equations.  If the 4 corners of the DC region rectangle you choose map to the 4 corners of the canvas, you have it right.